# Is it possible to create a >8 EiB sparse file anywhere?

Tags: filesystems, limit, sparse-file

Background: as part of trying to ensure complete coverage in my unit tests, I'm stress-testing some overflow checks.

So, I tried to create a 16 EiB sparse file.

However, on Linux/Btrfs this seems to fail at 8 EiB (2^63 bytes) rather than 16 EiB (2^64 bytes), likely because `off_t` is signed.

Is there any OS/filesystem combo which *actually*, rather than theoretically, allows creating such files?

(-1 omitted in each of the numbers above)

---

This works:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse_file bs=1 count=0 seek=9223372036854775807
```

This fails:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse_file bs=1 count=0 seek=9223372036854775808
```